# How to get server response in the NSUrlSession in background mode

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am uploading image on server Using NSUrlSession. i am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask for that bcoz in NSURLSessionUploadTask i have to set file which i cant.

Now my data uploading perfectlly in foreground and background mode but i can't find any way to get server response. According to this response i am changing things in my app.

I am using code from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595) which is good tutorial.
My server gives success or fail response according to upload status.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the `NSURLResponse` available in the completion handler of

```
[downloadTaskWithResumeData:completionHandler:]
```

In the tutorial you link to, the completion handler handled by the App Delegate is "dumbed down" by ignoring the completion handlers provided by the `NSURLSessionDataTask` class.

You need to move beyond the tutorial and use the API provided completion handlers to have access to the response.

Comment: But if i tried to use completion handler app display error that completion handler can not be used in the background mode and it crashed